# Add status for JIRA Issue while creating it using JIRA SOAP API and PHP

Tags: php, api, soap, jira

I am trying to create an Issue in JIRA(v6.2.5) through PHP script using JIRA SOAP API.

**Code:**

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://jira.xxx.com/jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
$token = $soapClient->login('username', 'passwd') or die('Username/Password is not correct!');
$issue = array(
    'type' => 2,
    'priority' => 3,
    'project' => 'TEST',
    'versions' => 'TEST',
    'summary' => 'Doing POC',
    'assignee' => 'samj1',
    'status'=> '3'
);
$soapClient->createIssue($token, $issue);
```

**Output**:

Issue is being craeted with all the fields.

**Problem I am facing**

**Status** of the issue is "**OPEN**" (whose numerical mapped value in JIRA is **6**) instead of "**IN PROGRESS**" (Numerical mapped value in JIRA is **3**).

So Can anyone help me to assign **In Progress** in stead of **Open**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not using SOAP as the [documentation states](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-api-status/jira-rpc-services/creating-a-jira-soap-client):

> JIRA's SOAP and XML-RPC remote APIs have been deprecated since JIRA 6.0 and will be removed in JIRA 7.0

But to answer your question when you create an issue in JIRA you cannot specify the starting status, it will be in the initial Status as defined by the workflow.

You would need to first create the issue and then transition it into the correct status following the transitions that are defined in your workflow to get to the right status.